When I open my update modal, the selected role does not appear in my dropdown
The first value in my dropdown appears selected. I do not want this, I want the value in the row I selected to appear in my dropdown.  Can anyone check my codes and help me with this?
I have a table where I display user data and a modal to update the user's information. When I click the "Update" button, the modal opens, but the first value in my dropdown is always selected by default. However, I want the role value from the selected row to appear in the dropdown.
Here’s my code:


$('#usersUpdateModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget); 
   var id = button.data('id'); 
   var role = button.data('role');
   var modal = $(this);
   
   // Populate the input fields with the selected row's data
   modal.find('input[name="users.Id"]').val(id);
   modal.find('select[name="users.Role"]').val(role);  // Here is where the role should be selected
});

@foreach (var k in Model.users)
{
    <tr class="text-nowrap">
        <td>@k.Id</td>
        <td>@k.Role</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#kullaniciGuncelleModal" data-id="@k.Id" data-role="@k.Role">
                Güncelle
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}


<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <label class="col-form-label">Role</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <select asp-for="users.YetkiId" class="form-select" required>
            @foreach (var y in Model.yetkiler)
            {
                <option value="@y.Id">@y.Role</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>



The roles in the dropdown are pulled from the "Yetki" table, which contains role information.
YetkiId is a foreign key (FK).
What could be causing the first value to always appear selected, and how can I fix this so the selected row's role appears in the dropdown when the modal opens?

data-id="@k.Id" data-role="@k.Role" - what is what here? Is @k.Role the id of a role, or its name? Your select options appear to have the role id as value, so you need to set that id using .val(), when you want to select one of those options via script.

The role here actually corresponds to the name in my 'Yetki' table, such as 1=Admin, 2=Teacher, ... ."

Right, so you got a role name, that would be "admin", and a role ID, that would be "1". The data-role="@k.Role" you output on the button, is what then - the ID, or the name?

a name , like this ;
Güncelle
look when I clicked i can see my role name but, I cant see on my dropdown

You set the name of the role in the data-role attribute. But the values of your options, are not the role name, but the role ID, <option value="@y.Id">. Setting the value of a select field requires you assign the value of the option as the select field's value, not the text content of the option.

'

Role



@foreach (var y in Model.yetkiler)
{
@y.Role
}


</div'  What changes can I make here or where exactly should I make changes in the code?I didn't quite understand what you meant.

You need data-role="1" on your button, so that this corresponds to the value of the option you want to select ...

I didn't fix it

Then you're probably still outputting the wrong values, I'm guessing. Verify what the attributes actually contain in the rendered HTML now.


The roles in the dropdown are pulled from the "Yetki" table, which
contains role information. YetkiId is a foreign key (FK).

I'm afraid that when you click the button, the options in the dropdown within the modal shall be different based on the button we click. Since we are working on MVC app, the view content is rendered before the page appearing in front of us, so that we can't change the content without reload the page content. That's what I said in comment about using ajax. I write another sample.
Here's the view, in my codes when I click the button, it will send a request to server to get the html content containing dropdown options. The content is hosted in a partial view.
<table>
    <tr class="text-nowrap">
        <td>user1</td>
        <td>Admin</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="ajax-modal"
                    data-url="@Url.Action("RoleSelectionModal", "Modal", new { roleId = "admin" })" >
            @* <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#RoleModal" data-id="user1" data-role="admin"> *@
                open modal
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-nowrap">
        <td>user2</td>
        <td>Guest</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="ajax-modal"
                    data-url="@Url.Action("RoleSelectionModal", "Modal", new { roleId = "guest" })">
            @* <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#RoleModal" data-id="user2" data-role="guest"> *@
                open modal
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="popup"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
            var url = $(this).data('url');
            $.get(url).done(function (data) {
                $("#popup").html(data);
                $('#RoleModal').modal('show');
            })
        })
    </script>
}

Here's my partial view, it's a modal.
@model IEnumerable<WebAppMvc.Controllers.RoleSelection>

<div class="modal fade" id="RoleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal For Role</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Role</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <select id="Role" class="form-select" required>
                            @foreach (var y in Model)
                            {
                                <option selected="@y.Selected" value="@y.RoleId">@y.RoleName</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Here's my controller and the test model I used.
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult RoleSelectionModal(string roleId)
{
    //query in "Yetki" table via YetkiId
    //combining with the roleId received in the parameter to determin which option is selected by default
    var result = new List<RoleSelection> { 
        new RoleSelection{ RoleId="admin", RoleName="Admin", Selected=roleId=="admin"},
        new RoleSelection{ RoleId="guest", RoleName="Guest", Selected=roleId=="guest"}
    };
    return PartialView("_RoleSelect", result);
}

public class RoleSelection {
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

====================================
Here's my code and it worked well,  could you pls help check it?
<table>
    <tr class="text-nowrap">
        <td>user1</td>
        <td>Admin</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#RoleModal" data-id="user1" data-role="admin">
                open modal
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-nowrap">
        <td>user2</td>
        <td>Guest</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#RoleModal" data-id="user2" data-role="guest">
                open modal
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="RoleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal For Role</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Role</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <select asp-for="Role" class="form-select" required>
                            <option value="admin">admin</option>
                            <option value="guest">guest</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $('#RoleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var userRole = button.data('role');
            console.info(button);
            console.info(userRole);
            $('#Role').val(userRole);
        });

    </script>
}



My dropdown for Role in modal has asp-for="Role" so that it will generate a selction which id is Role, that's why I used $('#Role'). By the way, my test is based on MVC app so that I have to put the event listener into @section Scripts to make sure the page has rendered completely, so that the listener could work well.

can ı send my all code because my code type different.                                                                   $('#kullaniciGuncelleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
var id = button.data('id');
var rol = button.data('rol');
var modal = $(this);
modal.find('input[name="kullanici.Id"]').val(id);
modal.find('select[name="kullanici.Rol"]').val(rol);

});



Rol



             @foreach (var y in Model.yetkiler)
             {
                 @y.Rol
             }
         


problem is here  i think
I don't enter the roles from outside, I just pull them from the table.

Do you have any suggestions for a solution that would be suitable for my coding?

Do you mean, each time you click the button to show the modal, the content of the modal is not fixed, but generated dynamically? Here the dynamic content is the select dropdown. And now you want to generate the dropdown select dynamically, and you also want to set different default selected option based on the click button?

In my humble opinion, you have <select asp-for="users.YetkiId" class="form-select" required> @foreach (var y in Model.yetkiler) {<option value="@y.Id">@y.Role</option> }</select> in your modal content, then I think the modal content shall be rendered at the same time when the main page is loaded, if you want to dynamic generate the modal content and dynamic set the default selecting option, you might need to create custom html content in the js method and append the content to Modal div. Pls correct me if I misunderstand your issue.

the modal content can be a partial view if you want. Let's say in the on('show.bs.modal event, we already get the role and id. We can create a controller action which will return Partial view, the partial view is the content of the modal, we can use the role and id we get in the event listener and write an ajax request to call this controller action, then we will get the partial view content as the response, then we can put the content into the modal div. Pls bear with my expression, anyway, you might take a look at this case, hope it helped.

In my humble opinion, you have  @foreach (var y in Model.yetkiler) {@y.Role } in your modal content, then I think the modal content shall be rendered at the same time when the main page is loaded, if you want to dynamic generate the modal content and dynamic set the default selecting option, you might need to create custom html content in the js method and append the content to Modal div. Pls correct me if I misunderstand your issue. –
yess, ı think problem is here. Other things working

I need to find a solution urgently. The example you gave seemed very different, I couldn't understand it.

There is actually a visual above that explains the problem. You can understand the problem better from there.

@fatmabaşar Hi, I updated my post with another sample.COuld you pls check whether is't helpful? I'm not very sure about your requirement to be honest.
